# What could be the best and optimal way to combine these two t-tests?

Tags: r

```
tframe <- data.frame(
p <- apply(bmiqbeta.m, 1, function(x) t.test(x ~ pheno.v)$p.value),
t <- apply(bmiqbeta.m,1, function(x) t.test(x ~ pheno.v)$statistic))
```

bmiqbeta.m is a large matrix containing the data,
where as pheno.v is the matrix containing 0s and 1s. The rows and coulmns are well matched for the operation, there is no problem with that!
But this way it takes a long time to process this and get the results since bmiqbeta.m has 300,000 rows.
So, I tired to assign the t-test values to a data frame

```
 tframe <- data.frame(apply(bmiqbeta.m, 1, function(x) t.test(x ~ pheno.v)))
```

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :      cannot coerce class ""htest"" to a data.frame

Any other methods to solve this, would appreciate that! And please be nice community, already given warning for bad choice of questions when I do the opposite.

Comment: You are seriously conducting 300,000 t-tests? Don't forget to adjust the p-values. I would probably use the Benjamini & Hochberg (1995) method, see `help("p.adjust")`. Anyway, you can speed this up by calculating t-values "manually" and then use one call to `pt` to get the p-values. Please provide a small reproducible example if you need more help.

Comment: I do am conducting 300K t-tests! Yeah, I will adjust the pvalues but for that I need pvalues first. And conducting t-tests manually, I don't think that is feasible in my case!

Comment: You might start by doing each t-test only once, and extracting both p-value and statistics.

Comment: @vib321 By "manually" I mean that you write your own (mostly) vectorized function instead of calling `t.test` 300,000 times. A t-value is rather simple to calculate after all.